# Function Pointer with Multiple Arguments

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a little problem with the C language.

Im tryin to make a pointer to a function with multiple arguments( structs, and variable ).

My function prototype is:

```
void db_insert(
    struct DataBase *db,
    struct auto_increment *a_i,
    enum db_insert_types db_insert_type,
    ...
);
```

and the pointer is defined like:

```
void ( *fct )(
    struct DataBase *db,
    struct auto_increment *a_i,
    enum db_insert_types db_insert_type,
    ...
);
```

I use the pointer like:

```
int main( ) {
    struct DataBase db;
    struct auto_increment a_i;


    void ( *fct )( struct DataBase *db, struct auto_increment *a_i, enum db_insert_types db_insert_type,... );
   fct = &db_insert;

    ( *fct )( &db, &a_i, db_insert_modele, 1, 2, 3, "asd", "dan", "mere" );

    db_initiate( &db, &a_i );

    db_free_mem( &db );

    return 0;
}
```

This causes my app to "Stop Working"

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: "*But the pointer makes my program crash.*", probably not, but how it is used, which you do *not* show us.

Comment: What do you mean with "makes my program crash"? Do you get a crash when calling the function through the pointer? How does the code for the pointer assignment and the function call look?

Comment: Edit: you were right, the call of the pointer causes the crash

Comment: And if you only replace `( *fct )` with `db_insert`, not any other code change then it is working again? Also I don't know if its important, but you write unnecessary parameter names in the function pointer definition and these names are equal to local variables of the main function

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the issue had nothing to do with the function pointer. The problem  was that `db_insert` was being called before `db_initiate`.